# dompdf problems with tables, can you help me?

Tags: dompdf, laravel-dompdf

I'm using dompdf in my laravel project, and I'm having problems rendering html in my dompdf, especially tables. It behaves in the ugliest way possible, and the more complex the table is, the more it doesn't behave well.

As I want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frpqs.png)

how is it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAMHb.png)

I tried to change the css of my html, but nothing helped, it works for some, but when you implement a new, different table it causes the problem again. I wanted it to be like an HTML page, where you press crtl + p and everything is fine to print. I wanted the html to be included in the dompdf the way it was.